# Express Gateway errors on https self-signed certificate even with certificate verification disabled in Node

Tags: node.js, ssl-certificate, self-signed-certificate, express-gateway

I am playing around and learning [Express Gateway](https://www.express-gateway.io/).  The getting started guide requires that I make calls to an https endpoint.  My organization runs all requests through a middlebox that sniffs https content and has its root certs installed on our machines.  So basically all https payloads are signed with the organization's own certs.

Basically when Express Gateway makes the call and sees this cert it doesn't trust, it throws an error.  I have tried to set `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` to temporarily disable certificate verification, but still I see the error and the connection is rejected:

[image]

How can I temporarily disable certificate verification in Express Gateway?

As a longer term solution, I've seen a post about how to get [Node to trust my OS certificates](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_extra_ca_certs_file) by setting the `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` environment variable, but I don't know which file to point to on my system as the certificate file

#### Update 1 (2020.26.02)

I followed Vicenzo's advice and tried to call the script directly rather than via an `npm script` but it doesn't work.  I've added a console log at the top of the `server.js` file to see the value of `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED`.  When I don't set the variable, and I try to proxy to an https service this is what I see:

[image]

When I set the variable, again executing the script directly, this is what I see -- the gateway still rejects the self-signed certificate:

[image]

Comment: How are you setting such environment variable? It appears to me you didn't set it correctly.

Comment: Hi Vincenzo!  I'm on Windows. I set the variable by running `set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` before running `npm start` from the same prompt.  The warning about "disabling certificate verification" (see next to last line in the screenshot) only shows up when I set that environment var.  That's why I think it was set correctly

Comment: @Vincenzo is there another way I should be setting that up?  Does Express Gateway itself have a relevant setting?

Comment: It seems apparently all correct, the only thing I would try to do is to set the variable and then instead of calling the NPM start script — try to call node index.js directly

Comment: @Vincenzo no dice.  I updated my question with results from your suggestion.

Comment: did you ever solve this problem? I am facing the same issue, even after setting the variable the logs show a warning but still, I get a bad gateway.